# Should the selectedindex or selectedvalue be used to set a asp.net dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu

I am wondering if there is a preferred or proper way to set the item in the dropdownlist in asp.net?

I am binding months to a list 0-13 items default selection is 0 months duration, and years 0-8 items and 0 years is the default selection.

As I know there are always going to be 12 months in a year, I could use selectedvalue or selectedindex without any perceived problem.

Is there a reason why I should not use either/or of the two properties to select a list item?

I hope this question is clear enough.

Comment: not sure who gets the tick? your answer are both acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest always using SelectedValue.... It's more predictable that way.

Imagine if you were told to add some new items, e.g "Please select" at index 0 and forgot to update your code!

Comment: Odds are that you are looking to read or save a value to a database. SelectedValue should represent the value in the database and while they may be similar, SelectedValue does NOT equal SelectedIndex. Thus, you are likely to be saving the wrong values to your database.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the SelectedValue when binding to an object within a DataSource. If you're populating the list manually with some numbers, then I see no reason to not use SelectedIndex.

### UPDATE

It's early, and I wasn't thinking straight. Always use `SelectedValue` as SelectedIndex is not predictable. Plus you know what the value is, so it's just easier.

Comment: Yes I am manually adding items to the list. However, it seems that SelectedValue IS the property to use.